# 504 Gateway Timeout error on Express.js when a timer is running

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, timer

I am getting "504 Gateway Timeout" error on my Express.js app when a JavaScript timer is running every 20 seconds.

This is my Express.js listener and the timer:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('ok.'))
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});

var items = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
]

let forParallel = require('node-in-parallel');
var request = require('sync-request');

setInterval(function() {
  forParallel(items, function(listItem) {
        request("GET", "https://example.com/?i=" + listItem);
        console.log("Done.");
  }, function () {
  });
}, 20000);
```

So, as you can see: I am using [node-in-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-in-parallel) to loop on the array `items` every 20 seconds parallely... each loop iteration should do a GET request to `"https://example.com/?i=" + listItem` ...

So.. Express.js works fine before the timer starts for the first time! but when the timer starts Express.js returns "504 Gateway Timeout Error"

Isn't the Express.js listener async?

**EDIT**: Note that the process of the GET request takes time (like 30 seconds per iteration) because it does something big.

Comment: What if you try using asynchronous requests instead? Besides, do you really mean it returns a 504 after only 20s? Isn't it supposed to happen after 60s unless configured otherwise?

Comment: @StockOverflaw - You saved my day! Using `request` module ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/request ) instead of `sync-request` worked! You can post this as an answer.

Comment: Generally speaking with JS: if it takes too long, look for synchronous stuff. JS "seems" multi-threaded because of callbacks, promises and the like, but it's not, it's only event-based with a _single_ process (called the event loop). Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, problem was synchronous requests preventing route listeners from answering in due time.